# Is it possible to get multiple signatures at once using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to generate signatures for accessing photos stored in AWS S3 using boto3 in python. Here's the code I'm using:

```
# pass in the credentials and generate an s3 session
s3_session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key)

# now create an s3 client
c = s3_session.client('s3')

signature = c.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                ExpiresIn=expiry_time,
                Params={'Bucket': bucket,
                        'Key': path
                })
```

I'm trying to do this for many files at once. Is it possible to pass in multiple keys at once (or more broadly, to get multiple signatures at once) instead of looping through this for every key? I tried passing a list in for the `path`, but I get a `ParamValidationError`.

Comment: I do not think it is possible with native Boto3. You have to loop through each key.

Answer (score 0):

The `generate_presigned_url()` function only generates one signature at a time.

Please note that it **does not involve a call back to AWS** -- the signature is calculated locally from provided information. Therefore, simply call it in a loop and you'll generate the results very quickly.

However, it is very strange that you wish to generate many signatures at the same time. The normal usage is to generate a Pre-signed URL at the time that the object is requested by your user. This way, the URL can be time-limited (eg 5 minutes). After 5 minutes, the URL will no longer function.

Many people seem to want to generate pre-signed URLs and save them in a database, but this is an anti-pattern since the URLs do not have an expiry duration related to the current user.

**Bottom line:** Generate pre-signed URLs as you need them, one at a time.